# sumif function in excel to display percentage based on text

Tags: sumifs

I am attempting to display a progress percentage in a single cell based on the choice of "completion" from a data validation list that spans multiple columns and cells.

I have attached a screen grab that will hopefully better explain.  I would like the "Overall status cell (B3) to display the percentage of "Completes" that will track overall progress of requirements.

I have narrowed to a "sumif" function based on research and former templates but cannot achieve the desired result.  Any help would be excellent.  Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do a `=(COUNTIF(C5:C100, "Completed")/COUNTA(C5:C100))`.

Obviously, you might want to change the range.

---

E2A: `=SUMIF` adds numbers together. Because you're looking at Text, you'll want to do a `=COUNTIF` and `=COUNTA`.

Comment: Amazing!  Thank you Chris.  Works perfectly.